# Regarding UNIX Move Command Override Protection

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Pasted a piece of code from the shell script transfer.sh

```
        if [[ ${ld} -eq ${eld} ]] ; then
            mv "$file1" "$FILESNEW/."
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
               echo "Move Command Failed-File ${fspec}"
            fi

            echo  "File ${fspec} Sucessfully Moved to ready directory "
        else
          echo "File ${fspec} line count mismatch: ${lc}/${elc}"
        fi
```

when i execute ./transfer.sh  move command waits for a prompt "override protection y/n" 
I dont want this prompt to appear when move command gets executed. How can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mv -f`. Option -f overrides any prompts ("force").

> -f, --force
>
> ```
> do not prompt before overwriting
> ```

Answer (score 1):

change `mv` to `mv -f`

[Man page for mv](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mv)

But remember, `-f` to force it means it *won't* prompt you so you better be sure you know how it's going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   if [[ ${ld} -eq ${eld} ]] ; then
        mv -f "$file1" "$FILESNEW/"
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
mv "$file1" "$FILESNEW/."
```

to:

```
/bin/mv "$file1" "$FILESNEW/."
```

(or wherever mv is located on your machine)

Comment: The problem wasn't an inability to find "mv"

Comment: @gary: But most likely `mv` was an alias, and using `/bin/mv` works because `mv` by default doesn't ask for confirmation.

Comment: exactly.  the problem with what I propose is the need to hardcode the path, yet there are ways around that (e.g. ``which mv``).  if there's an alias, adding switches may confuse the situation further.

Comment: Still No-Go.  Bypassing an alias won't fix the problem if the existing file does not have write permission.  In that case, the default is to ask for confirmation.  If trying to avoid an aliased "-i" was eqbridges's true intention, eqbridges deserves another down-vote for being unnecessarily obscure in proposing a solution.

Comment: Hmmm, trying to move a file that does not have write permission does not lead to `mv` asking for confirmation.  At least with GNU coreutils v7.0.  I also tried this with a read-only directory, and a read-only destination file (i.e. 0444).

Or, did you mean something else?